# Can't get value to calculate properly

Tags: c#, winforms

**Problem:**

The value `downtime` should end up with a value of `10`, but it is coming up with `42`.
Is it running more than `10` times?  Or is it just not calculating `turnTime` the way I want it to?

**Whole Scenario:**

This is just a simple app i'm setting up to help me calculate and balance elements for a game i'm working on.  The program simulates a gun being fired until it is either out of time for its turn, or it is out of ammunition.  The gun will attempt to reload if there is time left within the turn to do so, and then continue to fire.  This is supposed to simulate for 10 rounds, each with a 10 second turn.

The `downtime` variable represents how much time is wasted in each turn when the time remaining in the turn is not enough to either reload or fire.

**Code:**

```
        public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            currentAmmo = clip;

            for (float r = roundCounter; r < 10; r++)
            {
                turnTime = 10;
                Fire();

           }   
        }

        void Reload()
        {
            currentAmmo = clip;
            reloadCount++;
            turnTime -= reload;
            Fire();
        }

        void Fire()
        {
            if (currentAmmo > 0)
            {
               for (float a = currentAmmo; a > 0; a--)
               {
                   if (turnTime >= speed)
                   {
                       dpt = dpt + damage;
                       bullets++;
                       currentAmmo--;
                       turnTime -= speed ;

                       if (currentAmmo == 0)
                       {
                           if (turnTime < reload)
                           {
                               downTime += turnTime;
                           }
                           if (turnTime >= reload)
                           {
                               Reload();
                           }                               
                       }
                    }
                    if (turnTime < speed)
                    {
                        if (turnTime < reload)
                        {
                            downTime += turnTime;
                        }
                        if (turnTime >= reload)
                        {
                            Reload();
                        }                            
                    }
                }
           }
           if (currentAmmo == 0)
           {
               if (turnTime < reload)
               {
                   downTime += turnTime;
               }
               if (turnTime >= reload)
               {
                   Reload();
               }
        }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please only include the code that you are having a problem with.

Comment: You've discovered the meaning of life.

Comment: Calling Fire from reload is likely to mess up your algorithm.  I would avoid recursive calls that are not justified.

Comment: Also you should probably avoid using float in places where an integer will do - whilst premature optimisation is normally the foe of all that is right and proper, that's a heck of an inefficiency.

Comment: I have worked over the algorithm a few times, sometimes using while statements and removing the use of recursive calls, and every other statistic correctly calculates, except downtime.  Headscratcher.